# Hardware Machine Inventory Tool w/History

Tags: linux

I'm responsible for maintaining a listing of installed components and where on the machine they're connected.  I'm looking for a hardware inventory solution that doesn't force me to run a client software package, but will allow history of previously installed components.  The idea would be that we can track that the last 3 computers have XX video cards in PCI slot 0.

Has anyone worked with something similar?

It must be Linux compatible, or atleast web based with ties to a Linux capable web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in order to simply keep a record of hardware I need to utilize a database.  I'll be using Postgres & Libreoffice Base to do this.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/lhinv/ its written in perl and generates a list of hardware on a system.